# Rails engine: get parent app's name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I would like to know if a mountable Rails engine can retrieve the name of the parent application on which it is mounted.

I have looked through the [official Rails engine guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html), but could not find anything. Any sources or ideas?

Comment: A rails engine is made for a specific rails app, so why do you want to retrieve its name dynamically?

Comment: I would like to know this because I made my engine to be used for any app.

Comment: Then thats technically a gem, which shouldn't have any dependencies to its parent app. Maybe an example would clear things up? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Though this is an old answer, It's worth noting that Rails Engines can easily be mounted on multiple apps, and are often packaged as gems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm surprised no one answered this in more than a year.  You can use:

```
Rails.application.class.parent.name
```

Depending on where you use it you might need to make sure you start at the root rails module which makes this a safer choice:

```
::Rails.application.class.parent.name
```

Answer (score 5):

As of 2021, with Rails 6.x/Ruby 2.7, `class` does not have a method `#parent`.

I use:

```rb
::Rails.application.class.module_parent
```

to obtain the (technical) name of an application that my engine is mounted on.